# How do i send a post request to my Slack Weeb Hook

Tags: laravel

I have this code here. Basically i want to make a post request to my weebhook but it is not making a successful request and it is returning 400 as a status code , what i am missing

```
Route::get('/testime',function (){


   $response =  Http::post(env('SLACK_WEBHOOK'),[
        'content' => "Testing testing",
        'embeds' => [
            [
                'title' => "Test ",
                'description' => "URRA",
                'color' => '7506394',
            ]
        ],
    ]);
        return $response->status();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a 400 error, which is Slack telling you, your data is missing or malformed. To debug you can do the following. Which will most likely state what is wrong.

```
dd($response->body);
```

Your structure seems like nothing Slack supports, which most likely will be the error message. See examples [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22%2336a64f%22%2C%22pretext%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20above%20the%20attachment%20block%22%2C%22author_name%22%3A%22Bobby%20Tables%22%2C%22author_link%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Fbobby%2F%22%2C%22author_icon%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Ficons%2Fbobby.jpg%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Slack%20API%20Documentation%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2F%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Optional%20text%20that%20appears%20within%20the%20attachment%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22title%22%3A%22Priority%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22High%22%2C%22short%22%3Afalse%7D%5D%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fmy-website.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fimage.jpg%22%2C%22thumb_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fthumb.png%22%2C%22footer%22%3A%22Slack%20API%22%2C%22footer_icon%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fplatform.slack-edge.com%2Fimg%2Fdefault_application_icon.png%22%2C%22ts%22%3A123456789%7D%5D%7D), not certain this will even work.

```
$response =  Http::post(env('SLACK_WEBHOOK'), [
    'channel' => 'Your channel id',
    'text' => 'Testing testing',
    'blocks' => [
        [
            'type' => 'header',
            'text' => [
                'type' => 'plain_text',
                'text' => 'URRA',
                'color' => '#36a64f',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

]);